# How to return failure state in ADF .Net Activity

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I have created an ADF .Net Activity and returned **new Dictionary();**, but when the activity fails, the same Dictionary is returned showing the Pipeline is succeeded. How to return the failure state to Azure through .Net Activity. Is it that Possible?

```
return new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If we return the `Dictionary<string, string>() or null;` the pipeline will show Ready State.

But when we **throw the error** from the custom Activity, the slice will get failed.

```
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Write("Exception in userData: " + ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        return null;
```